# How can I embed a video on my website in order to work on an iPhone and what video format is required?

Tags: iphone, html, ios, video

I have seen several sites where they are able to create links to videos and they actually open on the video player of the iPhone, iPad or iPod.

This is obviously not a flash player video, and they don't seem to be embedded from youtube.

So I was wondering how can I add a video on my site that can be opened on an iPhone, and also what type of format is required for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML5 Video works on iOS devices, see http://html5video.org

and here is a decent player plugin 
http://videojs.org